# How can you enable the new embedded service stack swagger plugin without Feature.Html?

Tags: servicestack

ServiceStack now uses embedded resources for swagger. If you attempt to visit the swagger documentation without having Feature.Html enabled, the page fails to render.

How can swagger be enabled without requiring Feature.Html?